# Knife Tool - Constrain to global axis?

Tags: modeling, mesh, geometry, knife-tool

Is there anyway to cut a face whilst still constraining to a global axis regardless of the view orientation? The knife tool appears to constrain to 45 degree increments but this only appears to be relative to the screen. Is there a command I'm missing or perhaps another addon/script that can do it if the knife tool can't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot constrain the knife tool to an axis, you can try going into front view or side view and then making your cut using the 45 degree tool you talked about earlier

Comment: That's a pity, would have been quite useful.

Answer (score 1):

With Blender 3.0, the knife tool now has this feature plus others. To constrain to an axis you just press the axis key (x, y, or Z) like you would with other constraints. To cancel the constraint it seems that you just press the axis you constrained twice and then you should be able to freely move again.

Comment: 3.0 requires w8 ;(